# Purchased Songs are not showing in iTunes, AppleTV or iPhone

Tags: itunes-match

Why are some of my purchased song not showing in iTunes, AppleTV or available to play or download to iPhone.

Comment: Jason, you need to give us more to go on than that!   It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, etc.  Also let us know what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered.

Comment: I'm going to dupe this with the older similar question. Feel free to edit in some specifics if your case isn't a review of the closed question or explain exactly why the answer there isn't working for you. p.s. Big thanks for surfacing that unanswered question.